# How apt-get determines when to download translation file?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I've been able to successfully build local repository. When I do `apt-get` against this local repository everything works fine. Sample output-

```
Hit http://192.168.1.142 precise InRelease
Hit http://192.168.1.142 precise/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign http://192.168.1.142 precise/contrib TranslationIndex
Ign http://192.168.1.142 precise/contrib Translation-en
```

After checking that everything is working fine, I copied the repository to production server. Now I am getting below error message :

```
Err http://www.DOMAIN.com precise/contrib Translation-en
  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: A.B.C.D 80]
```

Why `apt-get` is trying to download translations file from one server (and if it doesn't find it gives error) but not from other?

I've checked HTTP headers and both servers are sending `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you use on the PC trying to fetch translation file?

Comment: Can you tell us what output does it give with `env | grep LC` for each machine? You can use http://paste.ubuntu.com site for the output

Comment: When you said you copied the repository, what files did you copy? (please update the question) did it include the translation files?

Answer (score 0):

The Apt configuration variable controlling whether or not to download language files is `Acquire::Languages`. You can change this variable to prevent Apt not to check for a language file.

To do so:

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Create a file naming `99-mysettings` in the directory `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` with admin privilege.

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99-mysettings
   ```
3. Then write this line below in the file and save it. Close the gedit.

   ```
   Acquire::Languages "none";
   ```

Now, `apt-get` should not check the language files.

You can do the same thing as a one liner in a terminal like this

```
echo 'Acquire::Languages "none";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99mysettings
```

Hope this will help. Now try again with `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: My question is why apt-get is downloading file from one repository but not from other? I am using same setting while fetching. On one server I see "Ign" on TranslationsIndex and "Err" on other server. Please re-read my question. Thank you.